# Find length of longest substring with non-repeating characters

Tags: bash, text-processing

I am looking to find the longest substring without repeating characters and return the length of that substring.

For example, given the following input:

```
abcbdbdsdfng
```

The output should be:

```
5
```

Explanation:

- the first such string is `abc` (length 3)
- the next possibility is `cbd` (length 3)
- the next possibility is `db` (length 2)
- the next possibility is `bds` (length 3)
- the next possibility is `sdfng` (length 5)

So, in the example `sdfng` is the longest sub-string containing only unique characters.

Comment: what do you mean by "count only once the character" ?

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase. The function needs the length of the longest substring such that all the alphabets in the substring are distinct. In this example of abcbdbdsdfng the selected and count substring is 'sdfng' and the length is 5.

Comment: For example 2 "abdefgabef" the expected output is 6. I suppose the longest substring there is ´abdefg´

Comment: While the [original version of this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/564848/1) was indeed very poorly worded, in its current state, it's a great question.

Answer (score 3):

Using POSIX `sh` syntax and one invocation of the `awk` utility:

```
<input awk '
  {
    cur = longest = ""
    n = l = 0
    while ($0 != "") {
      c = substr($0, 1, 1)
      if (i = index(cur, c)) {
        cur = substr(cur, i+1)
        l -= i
      }
      $0 = substr($0, 2)
      cur = cur c
      if (++l > n) {
        n = l
        longest = cur
      }
    }
    printf "\"%s\" (%d)\n", longest, n
  }'
```

Answer (score 3):

Finding the Longest Substring without Repeating Characters (LSRC) turns out to be quite simple in a shell (yes, portable `sh`) language (not fast, text processing is usually slow in a shell):

```
#!/bin/sh

str=$1  longest='' teststr=''

while [ "${str}" ]; do
    c=${str%"${str#?}"}              # extract one char to test it.

    str=${str#?}                     # remove the character from str.

    teststr=${teststr#*"$c"}$c       # Build teststr by appending $c
                                     # remove leading repeated char.

              l1=${#longest}         # length of longest found
              l2=${#teststr}         # length of tested string

    if     [ "$l1" -lt "$l2" ]       # if tested is longer than longest
    then   longest=$teststr          # store it in longest.
    fi

done

echo "$longest ${#longest}";         # print longest found and length.
```

---

Description
There are two general algorithms to [Find the Longest Substring without Repeating Characters](https://www.baeldung.com/java-longest-substring-without-repeated-characters)

The second, which is also called the "sliding window" approach works by:

1. Start with the whole input string in `str` (make `teststr` and `longest` empty).
   Then, in a loop:
2. Extract one character (`c`) from the front of `str`.
3. Check if `c` is repeated inside `teststr`.
4. If `c` is repeated keep removing characters at the front of `teststr`.
5. Once `c` is not repeated inside `teststr`: Add `c` to `teststr`.
6. Check if `teststr` is longer than `longest`. If it is, store that string in `longest`.
7. Once there are no more characters in `str` end the loop.

Steps 3,4 and 5 could be reduced to **one** string operation: "remove everything up to `c` (if it exists) and add `c`". If there is no repetition of `currChar` nothing gets removed, if there is a repetition, all chars before the repetition get removed in one step. That is done in shell with `${frontstr#*"$c"}$c`, just one variable expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Using POSIX `sh` parameter expansion operators, one invocation of the `printf` utility and several of the `[` utility:

```
string=abcbdbdsdfng

cur= n=0 longest=
while [ -n "$string" ]; do
  c=${string%"${string#?}"}

  new_cur=${cur#*"$c"}
  if [ "$new_cur" = "$cur" ]; then
    cur=$cur$c
    string=${string#?}
    l=${#cur}
    if [ "$l" -gt "$n" ]; then
      n=$l longest=$cur
    fi
  else
    cur=$new_cur
  fi
done
printf '"%s" (%d)\n' "$longest" "$n"
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler awk solution:

```
awk '
     {  teststr=""; longest=""; str=$0

        while (str>"")                        # until we test all chars.
        {
            char=substr(str, 1 , 1)           # extract first character.
            str=substr(str, 2)                # delete first character.

            sub("^.*"char,"",teststr)         # delete up to a repeated char (if any).
            teststr=teststr char              # Append the tested char.

            if(length(teststr)>length(longest)){longest=teststr}
        }

        print(longest,length(longest))

     }
    ' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With POSIX `sh` syntax and one invocation of the `sed` utility, you could do something like:

```
<input sed '
  # clean-up hold space
  x;s/.*//;x

  # insert a running ">" cursor
  s/^/>/
  :start
  />$/! {
    # pull the next character
    s/>\(.\)/\1>/

    # if what is left of > contains a duplicated character
    /\(.\).*\1.*>/ {
      # remove first char
      s/^.//
      b start
    }

    # does not contain a duplicated char. Is it longer than
    # the currently selected one?

    H; # append to hold space
    g;s/\n/>/;s/[^>]/./g
    # now the pattern space contains ...>....>... and we compare
    # the number of .s in the first two sections

    /^\([^>]*\)>\1[^>]/ {
      # it is longer, store in hold space
      g
      s/.*\n//;s/>.*//
      x
      s/.*\n//
      b start
    }

    # it is not longer
    g
    s/\n.*//;x;s/.*\n//
    b start
  }
  g

  # count the number of characters
  s/./o/g
  s/^/:|/
  :1
  s/|o\{10\}/x|/
  t 1

  s/$/9876543210/
  s/\(.*:\)\(x*\)|.\{9\}\(.\).*/\3\1|\2/
  y/x/o/
  /o/b1
  s/:.*//
  G
  s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/"\2" (\1)/
'
```

That gives the longest sequence of characters without repeated characters for each line of the input and assumes the input doesn't contain `>` characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ bash testing.sh abcbdbdsdfng
    5 sdfng

$ cat testing.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "${1}" | awk '
    {
            res=$1;
            for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
            {
                    idx=index(res,$i);
                    res=res""$i;
                    if(idx>0)
                    {
                            val=substr(res,idx+1,length(res));
                            res=val;
                    }
                    Arr[length(res)]=res;
                    max=(length(res)>max)?length(res):max;
            }
            print max,Arr[max];
    }' FS=""
```

Comment: Note that `FS=""` to split records into individual characters is not standard (though widely supported these days). Note that one can't use `echo` to print arbitrary data (unless you can guarantee the data doesn't start with `-` and doesn't contain backslash characters).

Answer (score 1):

Another one, also using `awk`, since this was a really interesting challenge.

```
awk -v s='abcbdbdsdfng' '
    BEGIN {
        m=""                                  # maximum length string
        while(s>"") {
            n=""                              # new string we are testing
            for (i=1; i<=length(s); i++) {
                c=substr(s,i,1)
                if (h[c]++) break             # break out if we have seen this char
                n=n c                         # add to the string and loop around
            }
                                              # end of source, or hit a duplicate
            if (length(m) < i-1) m=n          # save this string if it is longer
            split("", h)                      # erase the hash
            s=substr(s,2)                     # discard the front the source and loop
        }
        printf "%s (%d)\n", m, length(m)
        exit
    }
'
```

Comment: Note that you can clear a hash portably with `split("", h)`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you for that. I had been trying to avoid `delete h` and POSIX provides a simple `for...in` loop as its suggested way of clearing a hash ([search for `delete array`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)).

Comment: Yes, see https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=544

Comment: A `s=substr(s,2)` is good enough, the length is optional in POSIX.

Comment: There is no need to rebuild `n` on each loop, there are simpler alternatives. And therefor, the hash is also not needed.

Comment: @Isaac I'm sure there are better alternatives. I could have looked up Knuth, which probably has this algorithm. I liked your implementation (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Python version:

```
def longest(r): # Find longest different substring in 'r'
    for i in range(1, len(r)):
        if  r[i] in r[:i]:
            return r[:i]
    return r[:(i + 1)]

s = 'abcbdbdsdfng'

print(max(len(longest(s[i:])) for i in range(len(s)-1)))
```

Answer (score -2):

```c
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(char *s) {
  int count = 1;
  int max_count = 1;
  int j_start = 0;

  if (!s[0])
    return 0;
  else if (!s[1])
    return max_count;

  for (int i = 1; s[i]; i++) {
    for (int j = j_start; j < i; j++) {
      if (s[i] != s[j])
        count++;
      else
        j_start = j + 1;
    }
    if (max_count < count)
      max_count = count;
    count = 1;
  }
  return max_count;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have self-answered your question, but you give a C program with no indication of what it does.  Also, the question was tagged with the [tag:bash] tag, which usually means that answers should be relevant to the `bash` shell.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for a bash solution, can somebody help me to replicate this code on Bash in the best way?

Comment: Why would you want to de this in `bash` if you have a C program that does the same thing? String manipulation in the shell is not very elegant.

Comment: @Kusalananda sometimes a shell script can indeed be preferable because it offers more platform-independence than a compiled program (although these cases are admittedly rare).

Comment: @AdminBee C is arguably _more_ portable than a `bash` script though.

Comment: @Kusalananda I know what you mean. The point I tried to make (and which I have actually stumbled across myself) is that the _deployment_ of a compiled program to different target architectures is sometimes more cumbersome than distributing a shell script, in particular if the target(s) are a family of systems with slight differences in library versions etc. Of course, if you use very specialized shell features you can run into the same problem there, too.

Comment: @AdminBee We still don't know why the user wants to do this though.

Comment: @Kusalananda That is indeed true. I acknowledge that my comment didn't shed any light on this point.